# Invalid column name when inserting a new record

Tags: sql-server, delphi, pascal

I have a problem when I try to add new record to the database table from an `Adoquery` it shows me an error that says invalid column name the `Adoquery` is connected to `adoconnection` which is connected to the database.

I already checked the table name and the column name with the database they are matching - see the screenshot below.

Thank you for your help - I appreciate your effort to understand and help me

```
procedure TForm3.btn_addClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ADOQuery1.Close;
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(' INSERT INTO [ORGANISMES](NOM_ORG) VALUES  ("helloworld")');
    ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

```
INSERT INTO [ORGANISMES] (NOM_ORG) VALUES ("helloworld");
```

Comment: Can you show the schema for the table?  Also, doesn't SQL Server use *single-quotes* for strings, not *double-quotes*?  (I can't recall 100% if it allows both...)

Comment: Double quotes (`"`) are for delimit identifying objects. Single quotes (`'`) are for strings. The error is telling you the problem as the column `helloworld` had no context; presumably it should be a literal string.